# Transactional Replication Stopping At Distributor

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

My publisher is dutifully pumping data into the distributor but that is where it is stopping. I'm new to the realm of replication. I know that I can easily solve this by dropping and recreating everything but it seems there must be a more elegant solution.

- I sent through a tracer token from the publisher to one of the subscribers. The token made it to the distributor in several milliseconds but didn’t go past that
- I’m getting these 2 errors when I look at the subscribers
- The server "blah" is not configured as a distributor (sp_helpdistributor says it is)
- The process could not connect to distributor "blah"
- The publisher to distributor history looks good and says "No replicated transactions available"

Comment: Take a look at the distribution jobs. They'll have what server is being used for the publisher, distributor, and subscriber. Note that replication is very picky about what you use for the server name; it must be the name that the server knows itself by (located in sys.servers).

Comment: Thankss Ben. That helped tons. Can you put this in terms of an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication uses SQL Agent jobs to call an executable to deliver commands to the subscriber. If you open the job definition in SQL Server Management Studio, you can see all of the parameters that are being passed to the executable for various things like the publisher server and database, subscriber server and database, etc. I suspect that one of these is off.